# How do I uninstall Vivado on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: software-uninstall

I recently installed Vivado 2019.1 on Ubuntu by running `sudo ./xsetup`. I didn't pay attention where Vivado was installed, so by default it was installed in ***/tools/Xilinx/Vivado***. Because of that, I can't run the application there. Therefore, I decided to uninstall it. I run `./xsetup -Uninstall` but it gives me the error as below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.xilinx.installer.gui.panel.summary.SummaryPanel.b(Unknown Source)
at com.xilinx.installer.gui.panel.summary.UninstallerSummaryPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.xilinx.installer.gui.r.a(Unknown Source)
at com.xilinx.installer.gui.InstallerGUI.D(Unknown Source)
at com.xilinx.installer.gui.InstallerGUI.e(Unknown Source)
at com.xilinx.installer.api.InstallerLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

I googled it and also checked here but couldn't find out what to do.

Comment: You could change the permissions to launch it from there.

Comment: I tried that one before trying to uninstall. I got the following error:           application-specific initialization failed: couldn't load file "librdi_commontasks.so": libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
%

Comment: What about using `sudo`for the uninstall too - as you did for install ?

Comment: I tried that one as well, no changes...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You say "it was installed in /tools/Xilinx/Vivado. Because of that, I can't run the application there." and this is why you decided to uninstall it. Why do you think you can't run it from the default location? Please [edit] the output of `ls -l /tools/Xilinx/Vivado` into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 3):

Vivado is looking for a specific library called `libtinfo.so.5`.  The package can be found in Ubuntu repositories at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libtinfo-dev).

The `so.5` indicates this is the 5th version of the `libtinfo` library.  This version might not be installed on your system. `libdri_commontask.so` needs this library to be installed in a specific place.

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 19.04 trying to use Vivado 2019.1 SDK.  I got it working by running the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libtinfo-dev
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you explain how this answers the question asked?

Answer (score 0):

On 20.04

```
sudo apt install libtinfo5
```